# web part connection / webpart in display form

Tags: display-form, connected-web-parts

I have created site in SP2013 on premise. My requirement is when I click on title of a list item the information of that list item should open in adjacent to that

For that I am thinking of two ways:

1. Creating a web part connection by clicking on one web part the data should change in the other webpart on same page but in that the connection is made but I am not able to get result, I have taken 2 lists 1st with only 1 column in view & 2nd with 3 columns in view both with one same column & made a connection by using get parameter from, have I missed any basic condition ?
2. I have tried to add a webpart in customdisplay form of list , is it possible to have webparts in customdisplay form , I am getting error ...

Answer (score 1):

Rather than editing the display form - try this:

1. Create a view with all the fields that you need to show
2. Set the view style to "Preview Pane"

Result is very similar to your requirements i.e. when you hover on the item title the details are displayed in an area adjacent to that.